# c++ dynamic stuct pointer to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm having trouble dynamically assigning memory to a char array inside a pointer to a struct.
This is a homework assignment that has to use this struct outline:

```
struct Student
{
char *namePtr;
unsigned int score;
};
```

this is the part im having trouble with though

```
/***************************
 * takes value from temporary value and puts into dynamic allocated Student array
 ***************************/
bool updateStructPtr(Student **info, unsigned int index, char *name, unsigned int score)
{
try
{
    info[index]->namePtr = new char [strlen(name)+1];
    if(DEBUG) cout << "size for dynamic char: " << strlen(name)+1 << endl << endl;
    //copy char array into new array
    strcpy(info[index]->namePtr, name);
    info[index]->score = score;
}
catch (bad_alloc & param)
{
    info[index]->namePtr = NULL;
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

my prof said:
A glance at your code reveals that you do not seem to be dynamically allocating memory for the Student structure as specified in the first sentence of step 3-2 of the algorithm I provided you.

3-2. Dynamically allocate memory for a Student structure. Place the address of this Student structure in the array of structure pointers. You will also need to dynamically allocate just enough memory to store the name. Do not store the quote characters. Populate the fields of the Student structure with the two items from Step 3-1.

The pointers in the pointer array point to random locations in memory and you are trying to use these random addresses. That could certainly explain why the program crashes. Actually there are many ways to crash this program and all steps must be followed carefully to avoid this.

but i have no idea how to fix this or where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

SO isn't really intended for help with your homework.

That being said, the instructions from your teacher are quite elaborate and correct. You'll have to use `new Student` and `new Student[]` at one point or another to actually update the  Student ** `info` that is passed to you in order to add that new Student struct you're supposed to add.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `Student` instances are not allocated before the function is called. You would have to allocate a new instance of `Student` via `new Student` and store it into `info` at `index`.

```
info[index] = new Student;
```